# Determine the number of units in the ring $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Determine the number of units in the ring $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, where $p$ is a prime number.

I have no idea to find  the number of units in the ring of matrices. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

The units in $M_2( \mathbb{Z}_p)$ are precisely those matrices which are invertible.  A matrix $A$ (over any field) is invertible $\iff \det(A) \neq 0$.

Alternatively, a matrix $A$ is invertible if it has full rank when row-reduced.  For this to occur, notice that you have $p^2 - 1$ possibilities for the first row, and the second row can be *anything* so long as it is **not** a multiple of the first row.  Thus, we've arrived at a combinatorics problem.

Comment: @KajHasen Thank you very much for the nice idea. But how to determine the number of non-singular $2\times 2$ matrices?

Comment: @rama_ran, either of the two paragraphs can lead you to an answer, but the second paragraph is the most expedient.  Let's count the possibilities.  When we choose the first row, anything is valid except for a row of zeros (since that leads to a singular matrix), hence $p^2 - 1$ valid entries for row #1.  For the second row, anything is valid except for a multiple of the first.  There are $p^2$ total pairs of elements that are candidates to fill the second row, but some of them are invalid!  How many are invalid?

Comment: Given that $x$ of these pairs are invalid, notice that your final answer will be $(p^2-1)(p^2-x)$.

Comment: I want to count the number of invalid pairs x significantly. But the counting process of x=p is giving me trouble. Would you please write is bit more for x=p so that I clear all doubts. Thanks.

Comment: Let the 1st row be $(a,b)$. The send row would not be $(ka,kb)$. so $k$ cannot be $0,1,2,\cdots p-1$, which are $p$ in number. Therefore $x=p$. Would you please give a look on this argument and rectify if necessary.

Comment: That's indeed correct @rama_ran.  Every other possible pair of entries works for the second row.